# How to allow my maven plugin to access resources of a project where it is used?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven project which contain sub module :
mainproject, subproject-a, subproject-b

I'm developping a maven plugin (test-toto-plugin ) and i'd like this module check for example if toto.txt is present in src/main/resources for the project and each subproject and if it contains the line "toto".

When i include my test-toto-plugin in mainproject, it's called at each clean phase, i put a log to be sure about that, so it's called when i want, but it doesn't seem to access to src/main/resources of mainproject and each subproject, it seem that it access its own src/main/resources.

I use :

```
Paths.get("src","main","resources", "toto.txt");
```

To access the file, i'm almost sure it access test-toto-plugin /src/main/resources.

But i want to access mainproject/src/main/resources when it's called in main project, subproject-a/src/main/resources when it's called in subproject-a, subproject-b/src/main/resources when it's called in subproject-b.

Is it possible ?, any suggestion ?

Comment: 1) you cannot rely on current working directory to be set to anything useful. 2) each module should be treated as independent from the others.  Considered checking if toto.txt is present in the generated jar instead?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Just notice i use wrong vocabular, i edited my post, i used "module" word but wanted to say "plugin". Are plugin good solution for my purpose or i should find another solution (script for example) to do theses test ?. I lack of maven general knowledge.

Comment: What exactly does your "module"/"plugin" do and what invokes it?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have 2 version of my project, a prod and a beta-prod version which implies some modification contextRoot, persistence.xml, artifact name, and some properties file. I wanted my module with as parameter a boolean to check if project is prod, or if project is beta-prod. Testing for each submodule some specific files. I wanted the plugin to check before it try to compile that the projectis prod or beta-prod depend on variable. It can be done with a script, but i thought maven plugin could be a solution to achieve that purpose without even modifying jenkins integration job.

Comment: You cannot change the artifactId during the build. So adding a plugin to the build won't help you here. Additionally, it is usually not advisable to change the artifactId depending on the stage (BETA, PRODUCTION) of the artifact.

Comment: My purpose is not to modify it but to check its value which is different purpose. My plugin is there to test that developer didn't accidentaly provide wrong value for these different file by mistake.

Comment: Write a test invoked in your build and pass in a flag saying what you are . Much easier.

Comment: So i should put a test in every component using a variable to test prod and beta-prod ? I have the test which work, but the default is that i must put it in every sub-module (our project has 34 sub-module) so i thought it wasn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution to my problem reading code source of maven-resources-plugin : https://github.com/apache/maven-compiler-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/CompilerMojo.java

In my maven plugin Mojo class, i declare :

```
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${project.resources}", required = true, readonly = true )
private List<Resource> resources;
```

It will provide me the absolute path of resource of project where my plugin is used.
In the function execute of my plugin i use FileInputStream to get file content from absolute path (i just put functionnal code but ofcourse there is exception handling).

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(resources.get(0).getDirectory()+"\\toto.txt");
String body = IOUtils.toString(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

Executed in mainproject it will access mainproject\src\main\resources\toto.txt

Executed in subproject-a it will access subproject-a\src\main\resources\toto.txt

Executed in subproject-b it will access subproject-b\src\main\resources\toto.txt

And i just have to include my plugin to mainproject to make it work in each submodule.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the folder paths using the "*project.basedir*" or "*project.build.directory*" properties.

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.basedir}/src/main/resources", required = true, readonly = true)
private String sourceResourceDir;

@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.build.directory}/classes", required = true, readonly = true)
private String buildResourceDir;

public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    getLog().info("sourceResourceDir=" + sourceResourceDir);
    getLog().info("buildResourceDir=" + buildResourceDir);
}
```